# How to use multilevel inheritance in android

Tags: android

I am making an app in which i have to run an activity in background until the app is running.each activity related to this app is using first activity.how can it possible?

can i use the inheritance for this?

can anyone tell me any example of multilevel interitance in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a BaseActivity class that extends Activity and all other Activities will extend this BaseActivity. Then what ever happened in all other activities (like resume and pause) will also effect the actions of BaseActivity.

If you have to accomplish background task you better to see [android service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: thanks, i was thinking the same.But can you refer any example how can i use it in android...........

Answer (score 1):

You are already extending the `Activity` class in a base class, and again you are extending this base class in other class. This is itself an example of multilevel inheritance. I am posting an example that may be relevant for your question:

```
          public class basecls extends Activity{
           /*The base class*/
          }
          public class secondcls extends basecls{
           /* basecls extended by secondcls */
          }
```

You can extend the `secondcls` in another class, and the new class will inherit all super classes such that you can use the methods of its super classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your main activity is already using inheritance, since it extends the Activity class.

Comment: I know it that my main activity is already using inheritance.but i think you did not understand my query.I was asking that i have to implement such that my main activity work like base activity and another actives inherit it..... i want to know examples of that....

Comment: please check this.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html..
Activity class not a base class..it inherits from parents class as well....So its a example of multilevel inheritance in android,